# Success 'append' but not in right place

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to append from ajax result .

```
$("#result").append(' <tbody> <tr>  <td>' + no + '</td> <td> ' + val.FullName + '  </td> <td> ' +val.attendancedate+ '  </td>'  +
'<td>' + val.InTime + '</td> <td>' + val.OutTime + '</td> <td>' +val.total + '</td> </tr> </tbody>');
```

and here is my table

```
<div class="box-body">
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td> No </td>
                        <td> Nama Lengkap </td>
                        <td> Tanggal Kehadiran <td>
                        <td> Jam Masuk </td>
                        <td> Jam Keluar </td>
                        <td> Total Jam Lebih </td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <div id="result">
                </div>

            </table>
        </div>
```

there is no proble from ajax result. The problem is in `append`. 
Here is the example result . THanks

[image]

So how can i fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot write DIV like this in table. Instead write tbody and append in it Try this:

```
<div class="box-body">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td> No </td>
                <td> Nama Lengkap </td>
                <td> Tanggal Kehadiran <td>
                <td> Jam Masuk </td>
                <td> Jam Keluar </td>
                <td> Total Jam Lebih </td>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody id="result">
        </tbody>

    </table>
</div>

    $("#result").append('<tr>  <td>' + no + '</td> <td> ' + val.FullName + '  </td> <td> ' +val.attendancedate+ '  </td>'  +'<td>' + val.InTime + '</td> <td>' + val.OutTime + '</td> <td>' +val.total + '</td> </tr>');
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$(".table thead").after(' <tbody> <tr>  <td>' + no + '</td> <td> ' + val.FullName + '  </td> <td> ' +val.attendancedate+ '  </td>'  +'<td>' + val.InTime + '</td> <td>' + val.OutTime + '</td> <td>' +val.total + '</td> </tr> </tbody>');
```

Use after thead, you cant add div in table

Your html will be

```
<div class="box-body">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td> No </td>
                <td> Nama Lengkap </td>
                <td> Tanggal Kehadiran <td>
                <td> Jam Masuk </td>
                <td> Jam Keluar </td>
                <td> Total Jam Lebih </td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Append the results to the table, not the div.
Or, set the table id to `id="results"`